# Use the value in the last non-empty cell without using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple table:

[image]

I want to use the value in the last filled "**k**" row (currently in this example it would be the 8, but the week prior it would have been the 2, and next week it would be whatever is entered into the 6th) in a calculation.

Is there a way of doing this formulaically rather than using the dreaded VBA?

Comment: Try: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(K:K<>""),K:K)` or `=INDEX(K:K,MATCH(7^89,K:K))` or `=XLOOKUP(TRUE,K:K<>"",K:K,,1,-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using either of the one:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>M2</kbd>

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(K:K<>""),K:K)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N2</kbd>

```
=INDEX(K:K,MATCH(7^89,K:K))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>O2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,K:K<>"",K:K,,1,-1)
```

---

Here is an update please see it works

[image]

---

The solutions provided is working as per requirements

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

You don't like VBA? Yes, you just do not know how to use it!

You can create your own function using VBA and use it as well as any embedded function.
[image]

```
Function LastCell(ir As Range) As Variant
  If IsEmpty(ir.Cells(1).Offset(1, 0)) Then
    LastCell = ""
  Else
    LastCell = ir.Cells(1).End(xlDown)
  End If
End Function
```

Unfortunately I don't see a way how to perform this action with available functions.

**Another answer (using LOOKUP, INDEX or XLOOKUP) has the side effect and wrong behavior illustrated below.** You need to estimate what you need: the last cell in the continuous range or the last cell in a hole column:

[image]

**The potential wrong behavior** is to return the value out of the input table:
[image]

**Another gap in that solution** if the researched range is empty:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative, which will return the last numerical value in Column K...

```
=LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,K:K)
```

Comment: Your solution determines the last occupied cell in the column not the last cell in the continuous range of values. Look at my answer please.

Comment: @Domenic yours also works

Comment: @rotabor Yes, my solution returns the last numerical value in the range, regardless of whether the range is contiguous or not.  Afterall, the OP did not ask for the last cell in a contiguous range, but rather the last non-empty cell in the range.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks, I appreciate it.  Actually, it's similar to your INDEX/MATCH formula.  :-)

Comment: What can you say about the third picture in my answer?

Comment: @Domenic Thanks, yes I have tried yours, it works the same way as mine. Agree with that

Comment: @rotabor The number 22 is the last value (or last non-empty cell) in Column K.  Nowhere has the OP stated that there could be a non-contiguous range of cells, and the expected result in this case.

Comment: But agree it looks incorrect, no? To force your solution working you need to narrow the input range, e. g. K1:K11, which can be not convenient if the table expands.

Comment: @rotabor please dont assume anything, better you should read the post. And see what OP is expecting.

Comment: @rotabor But why are you assuming that there might be a non-contiguous range of cells?  And, even if there is a non-contiguous range of cells, why are you assuming that the desired result would be as you've described?

Comment: Sure, OP didn't fully specify requirements, and your solution can be good for him, but it will not work if any non-empty cell is below the table.

Comment: @rotabor That's fine, but no conditions were stated.  So rather than making an assumption, you could have asked the OP to clarify, just in case you were right.

Comment: The problem with your solution is not in the statement but is in that fact that it can return the result which is out of the processed table.

Comment: Or just think if the table can have the bottom total row...

Comment: Again, though, you're making assumptions.  :-)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I assume only OP means the continuous range. But it's the least important. The most important to do not return the result which is out of the input table.

Comment: Another gap in this solution if the researched range is empty.